# Pass msbuild parameters to dotnet run command

Tags: msbuild, .net-core, dotnet-cli

We can pass msbuild arguments to dotnet build:

```
dotnet build MyApp.csproj /p:SolutionDir=C:\MyApp
```

How can we do the same with `dotnet run`?

This does not work:

```
dotnet run MyApp.csproj /p:SolutionDir=C:\MyApp
```

The use case we have in mind is to use `dotnet watch` with the `run` command and to pass msbuild parameters to the `run` command's implicit `build` step.

Answer (score 4):

```
dotnet build MyApp.csproj /p:SolutionDir=C:\MyApp & dotnet run myApp.csproj --no-build
```

Answer (score 3):

In dotnet 6 or later you can provide `-p, --property` arguments for the run command as well.

```
> dotnet --version
6.0.200
> dotnet run --help
Description:
  .NET Run Command

Usage:
  dotnet [options] run [[--] <additional arguments>...]]

Options:
  -c, --configuration <CONFIGURATION>  The configuration to run for. The default for most projects is 'Debug'.
  -f, --framework <FRAMEWORK>          The target framework to run for. The target framework must also be specified in the project file.
  -r, --runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>   The target runtime to run for.
  --project <project>                  The path to the project file to run (defaults to the current directory if there is only one project).
  -p, --property <property>            Properties to be passed to MSBuild.
  --launch-profile <launch-profile>    The name of the launch profile (if any) to use when launching the application.
  --no-launch-profile                  Do not attempt to use launchSettings.json to configure the application.
  --no-build                           Do not build the project before running. Implies --no-restore.
  --interactive                        Allows the command to stop and wait for user input or action (for example to complete authentication).
  --no-restore                         Do not restore the project before building.
  --sc, --self-contained               Publish the .NET runtime with your application so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine.
                                       The default is 'true' if a runtime identifier is specified.
  --no-self-contained                  Publish your application as a framework dependent application. A compatible .NET runtime must be installed on the target machine to run your application.
  -v, --verbosity <LEVEL>              Set the MSBuild verbosity level. Allowed values are q[uiet], m[inimal], n[ormal], d[etailed], and diag[nostic].
  -a, --arch <arch>                    The target architecture.
  --os <os>                            The target operating system.
  -?, -h, --help                       Show command line help.

Additional Arguments:
  Arguments passed to the application that is being run.
```